# Get HTML Element from WebBrowser Control in VB

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and coding in VB. 
I have a form with a WebBrowser object in it. 
I have control over the HTML on the pages.

I need the user to be able to select a portion of text in the WebBrowser object and save it.
In the save process, I need to capture the selected text, the ID of the HTML element that contains the selected text, and the URL. Then when the user goes back to that page, the program can place an icon on the page right next to that object.

I do not have any code to accomplish this yet, I do not have much experience with the WebBrowser object so I didn't even know where to start.  I can however give the names of my form objects and inform you that all of the html elements have an ID.

```
Form : frmContent
WebBrowser : wbContent
```

I am guessing that I could even record coordinates of the selected portion of text instead of the html element.  Either way, the final outcome needs to save a list of these locations paired with their url so that for every saved "bookmark", there will be an icon placed on the page of that url in the saved location of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that this works rather well for me.

```
GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition)
```

I was able to set this to a variable and then able to get the attributes from the element.

```
Dim bookmarkElement = wbContent.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition)
Dim elementID = bookmarkElement.GetAttribute("id").ToString()
```

Problem solved.